# How to work with white artwork in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, white

Regarding Adobe Illustrator - I am trying to create a vector file that an imprinter will use to imprint my image on to T-shirts.  The shirts will be black and I want my image to be in white.

Questions - What do I need to do in AI to make the image come out white when it's printed?

Also, how might I be able to see what the imprinter will be printing?  I see a "preview" option but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why is the `Preview` option not what you're looking for? Does it lack something?

Answer (score 9):

Simply use any single color for the artwork. It doesn't *have* to be white in the file. You simply tell the printer to print the art white.

This is, unless you are using some online printer..... then...

Draw a black rectangle on a new layer. Move the layer below all other layers. Select the black rectangle and set it to **non-printing** using the `Attributes Panel` (window > attributes) then lock the layer. Create your artwork, in white, on a layer above the black rectangle layer.

You can then both see what will be printed and work with white shapes easily.

Comment: Or you can also work in black, then change everything to white once you're done.

Comment: ^^^ That's what I would do.  Much easier than all this "non-print" junk.