# White ink on black paper - how should I knockout a stroke around some text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, screen-printing, apparel, white

I am preparing artwork to be sent to a printer for the production of custom umbrellas. We want to print a logo on black fabric with 2-inks: white-spot and orange-spot (PMS 021) colours. The path in the picture is the stroke for the type. That's the one I want to be black, the fabric. Shown below is only one character coloured in orange.

[image: current artwork]

How do I get a stroke on an object to knockout underlying white ink and to not print on the stroke at all so that it ends up looking like the second image below? With 0% C 0% M 0% Y 0% K process swatch?

[image: desired result]

And how can I preview it? We don't have black paper nor white ink.

Comment: This fully relies on how the printing company processes the file - Is it screen printing? your best bet is to ask them.

Comment: Yes, screen printing, that's the way they do it.

Comment: Your questions might be answered in these two existing posts: [**How should artwork be setup for T-shirt printing?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36272/8708) and [**How to work with white artwork in Adobe Illustrator?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36493/8708)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you simply use black (just like you are doing for the background) for the stroke on the text.

To make it easy, make your black a CMYK black, instead of a spot – then you can advise the printer to simply ignore all CMYK and print the spot plates only.

To visualise as you're working, bring up the "Separations Preview" (Window menu) to see a list of inks: it should show CMYK plus your two spot colours. Making sure Overprint Preview is turned on, you then turn off CMYK plates to see your white and orange plates in isolation. Only catch is you won't see white ink against the white artboard so temporarily colour your white ink with a bit of magenta or whatever.

Comment: I think that is an excellent answer. I would add the traditional colouring for a knockout line is cyan when using spot colours. Your personal printer will (most likely) translate your spot colours into CMYK so print away, it should be fine (following the above advice). You will use a lot of black ink by the look of it, so you might want to figure out how to limit that.

Comment: @Ward huh? If your printer is converting Pantone spot colors into CMYK, get a new printer...

Answer (score 0):

Select the path and that white burst.... choose `Object > Compound Path > Make` from the menu.